# Change the specified string to QDateTime

Tags: qt, qdatetime

```
QString timestr("Fri Jan 5 14:03:11 CST 2018");
QDateTime time1 = QDateTime::fromString(timestr, "ddd MMM d hh:mm:ss CST yyyy");
qDebug() << time1.toString("yyyyMMdd");
```

I try to covert the string to an easier time description, however it failed. What could possibly be the problem with my QString?

Comment: Could you display your result, and try to be a bit more precise?

Comment: To me that code returns "20180105", 
and that is what is expected, what is your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i have fixed this problem.

Comment: The problem is that there was never a problem.

Comment: Because my language is not english, so it failed

Comment: In your question, it does not say anything about it, just as you expected the community to help you? I recommend you read [ask] and [tour] and improve your future questions since otherwise you will receive more downvotes and you will limit your publications.

Answer (score 0):

\note Unlike the other version of this function, day and month names must
be given in the user's local language. It is only possible to use the English
names if the user's language is English.

Note also this is the system locale, not the default locale you may have set in QLocale. To parse an English date string like this you will need to use QLocale::fromString() on an English language instance. So the following code will return correctly.

```
QLocale loc(QLocale::English);
    QString timestr("Fri Jan 5 14:03:11 CST 2018");
    QDateTime time1 = loc.toDateTime(timestr, "ddd MMM d hh:mm:ss CST yyyy");
    qDebug() << time1.toString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Hope it can help others with the same issue.